# Import multiple email attachments from 1 email in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, email, azure-logic-apps

I am currently receiving an email with 2 email attachments.  I only care about pulling in one of those attachments "Delivery Sales" and I don't care if I pull in or disregard the other.

My workflow should be:  Run when new email is detected > Grab attachments > Push attachment to Blob > Archive Email.

I can get all of these to work (and it even archives the email) but it will error out on the archive step because it seems to fire it off twice (once for each attachment it seems).

So how can I pull in the email, throw the attachment to blob, and then archive the email into another outlook folder?

Below is my current setup.  I have tried moving the email move to outside the loop (still fails), I have also added a condition to look at the attachment names, true/false, still fails.

The email arrives in a shared email box, the move now seems to take a while and times out with a status of "BadGateway"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue appeared to be in the move toe mail folder I had selected an "Archive" folder that was on the same level as my inbox.  My Outlook for whatever reason didn't like that.  So I clicked on Inbox and navigated to "Archive".  I then re-ran and it worked just fine.